# Spyrograph design

Tags: java, panel

I'm trying to draw a circle rotating around a circle in a panel that I created (not jpanel). The first circle is a larger circle with center M and radius R. the second circle has center P that is a point on the 1st circle's perimeter and point T which is a radius that connects to the top of the circle. Now, point P needs to move around the the 1st circles perimeter while point T needs to rotate clockwise as well. I understand how to code this, but mathematically, I can't get it to work.

I have the first circle as:

```
int middle = 50;
int radius = 20;

int deg = 0;
while ( deg <= 360 ) {
x = middle + (int)(Math.cos(deg)*radius);
y = middle + (int)(Math.sin(deg)*radius);
panel.drawNextPixel(x, y);
deg++;
```

}

What do I need to do for the other circle and points? Thanks!

Comment: Work out the coordinates on the second circle as if the circle were centered at `(0, 0)`, and then shift them by `(x, y)`.

Comment: @NPE Keep track of the point (as an angle `ω`) on the center circle where the center of the outer circle should be.  Then shift by `(rcosω, rsinω)`.

Comment: `deg` should vary from 0 to 2π